# Cloudfront not caching missing pages

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

So to explain a problem I have an S3 bucket with static site and CloudFront as CDN. On S3 the index and error document are both `index.html`. So when I go to `subdomain.example.com` I get served `index.html` and get `Hit from Cloudfront`.

However my static page is Vue page with router and default path is `/en` so when I reload the page `subdomain.example.com/en` I get `Error from cloudfront`. The same happens if I try to refresh it after it got hit the first time. Everything else(.css, .js, .img ...) is cached ok.

I have S3 connected in origin like that: 

`Origin Domain Name: s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Origin Path: /subdomain.example.com
Origin ID: subdomain.example.com
Minimum Origin SSL Protocol: TLSv1
Origin Protocol Policy: HTTP Only
Origin Response Timeout: 30
Origin Keep-alive Timeout: 5
HTTP Port: 80
HTTPS Port: 443`

On Cloudfront I also have custom error responses for 400,403 and 404 all pointing to `/index.html` with code 200.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

error image:
[image]

error image with no error handling on Cloudfront
[image]

Comment: are invalidating cache ? inside invalidation tab using   * and /index.html

Comment: Yes I invalidated cache and it doesn't help. But I don't do that regulary.

Comment: to see impact immediately required to invalidate cache.can you add screenshot of error.

Comment: Yes when I'm doing changes I clean the cache, however this does't help. I've added an image

Comment: Did you check if you are able to enter page on s3 endpoint like http://bucket-name.s3-website.Region.amazonaws.com ? Could you check if it works there

Comment: Yes on bucketname.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/en I get the proper response (index.html)

Comment: then do one thing in your bucket selection in CF copy page bucket name without http and saved. this will worked. i faced this issue earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Open Cloudfront origin setting

edit Origin Domain name :

from `bucketname.com.s3.amazonaws.com` to

`bucketname.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

it will wrk.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: So I've changed my domain to: subdomain.example.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com. And it doesn't work. I've also removed all error handling on CloudFront side, will update question with new response headers.